# How to use FOREACH in a PostgreSQL LOOP

Tags: postgresql, loops, foreach, format

I am trying to write a very simple pgsql statement to loop through a simple array of state abbreviations.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.showState() 
 RETURNS text AS 
 $$
 DECLARE
 my_array text[] := '["az","al", "ak", "ar"]' 
 BEGIN
     FOREACH state IN my_array 
     LOOP
         RETURN SELECT format('%s', state);
     END LOOP;
 END;
 $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM showState();
```

I am using PostgresSQL version 11+. I keep getting an error `ERROR: syntax error at or near "BEGIN"` The output I want to see here is just seeing the state abbreviation printed in the results window for now. Like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: [Edit] the question an show what is *before* `FOREACH`. Ideally show the whole function/procedure/`DO`/...

Comment: And you cannot just `SELECT` in `PL/pgSQL` without the selected data going somewhere (variable, return buffer, ...). So your target-less `SELECT` will be the next problem.

Comment: Please show us your complete stored procedure (or function). What exactly are you trying to achieve here? What is the output you expect?

Comment: OK, I have made the suggested edits. I am new to this, so I am not sure how (or why) it has to be in a function.

Comment: That code doesn't produce the error you posted. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4e317e7935fffa02b65ca4522726d239. You should really post code that produces the error, if you want help.

Comment: The actual error has been updated in the question to reflect what I am seeing now. Apologies.

Comment: There is already a built-in function for this: `unnest()`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3812ec8dd7c486e2e1f67775152b4406

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There's a `;` missing after `my_array text[] := '["az","al", "ak", "ar"]'`.
- `'["az","al", "ak", "ar"]'` isn't a valid array literal.
- If you want a set returning function, you need to declare its return type as a `SETOF`.
- The `ARRAY` keyword is missing in the `FOREACH`'s head.
- `state` must be declared.
- You need to use `RETURN NEXT ...` to push a value into the set to be returned.
- `format()` is pointless here, it doesn't effectively do anything.

With all that rectified one'd get something along the lines of:

```
CREATE
 OR REPLACE FUNCTION showstate()
                     RETURNS SETOF text
AS 
$$
DECLARE
  my_array text[] := ARRAY['az',
                           'al',
                           'ak',
                           'ar'];
  state text;
BEGIN
  FOREACH state IN ARRAY my_array 
  LOOP
    RETURN NEXT state;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=abb0c31a2475008a656935cf687bb67d)

Comment: That works great! Apologies for the earlier errors; I am learning this on-the-fly.  I do have a follow-up question: lets say that instead of just returning the text, I want it to run another function that takes a state as a parameter like this: `SELECT * my_schema_my_function(state)`.  How would I alter the above? (Ex: `RETURNS void` ... `LOOP  SELECT * my_schema_my_function(state END LOOP;` Would that work?

Comment: @gwydion93: A scalar function? Just apply it to `state` before returning: `RETURN NEXT my_schema.my_function(state);` (Though I start to suspect you're using functions in places where they aren't needed and simple set operations would fare better...). But in general one question per thread. If you have another question open a new one.

Comment: Thanks; I may add a separate question to address this if I can't find an adequate solution. My goal here is to iterate through an array of state abbreviations and run a function that creates a table based on the input state parameter. Trying to automate the process so I don't have to manually run it for each state.

Comment: @gwydion93: Hmm, just a side note here, but yes, or even worse, that sounds suspiciously like you're up for a very, very bad database design that'll cause you a lot of pain in the future. I suspect every such table for a state looks the same and holds the same type of data? Then have exactly *one* table, for all data for all states. Just have an *extra column* in that table that designates the state a row belongs to.